# Reshaping data frame using a custom technique

Tags: r, reshape

The following is a sample of my dataset

```
df1<- read.table(text=" Month Crime
2010-12 Anti-social-behaviour
2010-12 Anti-social-behaviour
2010-12 Anti-social-behaviour
2010-12 Robbery
2010-12 Robbery
2010-12 Violent-Crime
2010-12 Violent-Crime
2010-12 Theft
2011-01 Anti-social-behaviour
2011-01 Anti-social-behaviour
2011-01 Anti-social-behaviour
2011-01 Anti-social-behaviour
2011-01 Arson
2011-01 Arson
2011-01 Theft
2011-01 Theft
2011-01 Theft
2011-01 Theft
2011-01 Theft", header=TRUE)
```

I intended to convert it into the following format to be able to analyse it.

```
Month      Crime                   Frequency
2010-12    Anti-social-behaviour   3
2010-12    Robbery                 2
2010-12    Violent Crime           2
2010-12    Theft                   1
2011-01    Anti-social behaviour   4
2011-01    Arson                   2
2011-01    Theft                   5
```

Since I was not familiar with the reshape packages, and I wanted to educate myself on using base functions, I formulated my own approach:

```
#convert months to factor
crimeData3$Month<- factor(crimeData3$Month, ordered=TRUE)
#calculate instances of each factor level
instances<- table(crimeData3$Month)
mySeq<- numeric(0)
myseqFinal<- numeric(0)
#append letters to each crime for each factor level, to identify crimes at month-level
for (i in 1:length(instances)){
mySeq<- rep(LETTERS[i], times=instances[i])
myseqFinal<- c(myseqFinal,mySeq)
}
crimeData3$CrimeNew<- paste(crimeData3$Crime, myseqFinal, sep=" ")
crimeData3$CrimeNew<- factor(crimeData3$CrimeNew, ordered=TRUE)
```

What I hoped to do after this was to calculate frequency of each crime. Since all crimes were uniquely labelled at month level, I thought it would be easy to calculate the frequency and simply add the results in the same order to a new dataframe.

However, as soon as I apply the table function to crimeData3$Crime, the order of crime gets messed up.

Is there another, simpler approach? Can my code be manipulated to provide the solution? I would appreciate any help using base functions and also specialised ones.

Many thanks.

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for `data.frame(table(df1))`?

Comment: Ouch! How elegant! I would have never thought about that; I only applied table for individual columns/rows!

Comment: If you have any criticism/advice/comment to add regarding my code too, that would be kind of you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your thinking wasn't too far off. The next step would have been to `aggregate` your output. Consider the following:

```
aggregate(CrimeNew ~ Month + Crime, crimeData3, length)
#     Month                 Crime CrimeNew
# 1 2010-12 Anti-social-behaviour        3
# 2 2011-01 Anti-social-behaviour        4
# 3 2011-01                 Arson        2
# 4 2010-12               Robbery        2
# 5 2010-12                 Theft        1
# 6 2011-01                 Theft        5
# 7 2010-12         Violent-Crime        2
```

As to improving your code, there's no need for the `for` loop:

```
myseqFinal <- rep(LETTERS[seq_along(instances)], times = instances)
```

---

However, as mentioned in the comments, you can just use `table` on the two columns of your data, and wrap that in `data.frame`. Since you seem to be concerned about the order of your rows and the exclusion of missing values, I've added a few more lines to show how to get to your desired output:

```
out <- data.frame(table(df1))
out <- out[order(factor(out$Month, ordered = TRUE)), ]
#     Month                 Crime Freq
# 1 2010-12 Anti-social-behaviour    3
# 5 2010-12               Robbery    2
# 7 2010-12                 Theft    1
# 9 2010-12         Violent-Crime    2
# 2 2011-01 Anti-social-behaviour    4
# 4 2011-01                 Arson    2
# 8 2011-01                 Theft    5
```

Comment: I am truly jubilant! Thank you so much for educating me on table + the function I wrote!